# Сравнить даты в vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

как сравнить даты в формате `Y-m-d`, дату из базы `2019-06-25 13:59:07` и текущую дату

пробовал так но ругается на format

```
newTask(date){
      var today = (new Date()).format( 'Y-m-d');
      var dateTask = (new Date(date)).format( 'Y-m-d');
      alert(today);
}
```

Comment: Vue тут не при делах.

Comment: jquery вроде использует format?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: не понял, в базе у меня дата со временем, мне нужно сравнить только даты, без времени